# Could not find module (or one of its dependencies) при использовании ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

Я пытаюсь импортировать код из C++ в Python с помощью модуля ctypes, но при попытке импорта выдаёт ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    libtest = CDLL('C:\\test\\libtest.so')
  File "C:\Users\grisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\test\libtest.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Код Python

```
from ctypes import CDLL

libtest = CDLL('C:\\test\\libtest.so')
libtest.hello()
```

Код C++

```
#include <iostream>

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Компилировал код с помощью этих команд (использовал MinGW64)

```
g++ -shared -c -fPIC test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so test.o -o libtest.so
```

Comment: Библиотеку для Linux вы хотите использовать в Windows?

Comment: Это библиотека для Windows, она скомпилирована в винде.

Comment: Не гани братан. Для Windows dll-ки нужны.

Comment: Всё окей, с dll-кой работает.

Comment: Ну так что - я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да, ответили. Всё работает.

Comment: @Александр Так оформите в виде ответа. Только без "братанов" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С созданием длл всё немного сложнее, для использования в Python нужно перед объявлением функции добавлять extern "C" и определять соглашение о вызовах, только тогда CDLL сможет нормально подключить ваш файл

[Вот тут, см. Раздел своя DLL и её использование](https://habr.com/ru/post/499152/)

Только там в паре мест опущено #include <Windows.h>

Ну и корректно собрать длл удобнее всего, на мой взгляд, с помощью cmake

[Вот тут неплохой гайд именно на сборку](https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2016/08/use-cmake-to-help-build-and-use-windows.html)

Но во втором нужно в хэдере добавлять extern "C" ещё, перед определениями функций

Ну и у вас если динамическая библиотека на Windows, думаю всё-таки корректнее сделать расширение dll, потому что это тоже может стать причиной какой-нибудь ошибки

Comment: Если бы проблема была с extern "C", то не находило бы функции (из-за манглинга имен), а не библиотеку целиком. Тут проблема была именно в том, что компилировался линуксовый so вместо dll.